# viewDidLoad not being called

Tags: objective-c

I'm working on a small application and I'd like an alert box to be shown as soon as the application is launched.  I thought that putting the code into viewDidLoad would cause this to happen, but it appears not to be.

What I would like to be able to do is an alert show up twice.  The first one will be for player 1 and the second for player 2.  Right now I'm just working on getting the first one working.

Is this the correct way to approach this or is there a better way?
Thanks.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"here...");
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Player 1" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert show];
[alert release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
NSLog(@"Entered: %@",[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text]);
}
```

---

the view controller only consists of these methods:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    BoxView* myView = [[BoxView alloc]
                      initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.view = myView;
    [myView release];
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: I think it's questionable at best to show an alert out of viewDidLoad.

Comment: I'm a very new Objective-C programmer.  Is there something you would suggest that would be better?

Comment: can you show us where you build the view controller that contains that view?  the view is loaded lazily, so the viewdidload won't fire until someone asks for the view.  the better place to show an alert is on viewDidAppear:, but that won't get called either until you get sorted whatever's preventing the viewDidLoad.

Comment: There really not much in the view controller besides this method

`- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        BoxView* myView = [[BoxView alloc]
                          initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.view = myView;
        [myView release];
    }
    return self;
}`

Other than that everything is created in a separate UIView.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create and Present modal view controller programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867447/create-and-present-modal-view-controller-programatically)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `viewDidLoad` is way too early. There's no interface yet! Wait until at least `viewDidAppear:`.

See my very similar answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15867468/341994

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Where would viewDidAppear be located?  I have a viewDidLoad in the view controller but there's no viewDidAppear.  Do I have to create that method "manually"?

Comment: Yes, if the template doesn't give it to you, you just have to write your own override. So too for *any* class you're subclassing. Here's the section of my book about subclassing and overriding in order to receive an event: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch11.html#_subclassing_2 And here's my discussion of view controller lifetime events like this one: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_view_controller_lifetime_events